# How to quickly recover an increasing array with 2 elements randomly swapped?

Tags: java, algorithm

If I have an array `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, `A` is an increasing array, with no duplicate elements. If I swap two elements, let's say `4` and `7`. I get array `B = [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4]`.

Given array `B`, what's the fast way to recover `A`?

Currently, the naive way is using the Collections sort method sort the array and compare to get the two different indexes, this cost `O(n)` space as well as `O(n)` time.

To make the question clear, here you are given input `B` and should output `B`

Comment: Not really any clever way imo, except just iterating in O(n)

Comment: What way did you come up with, and why do you think this could be done faster?

Comment: Randomly swapped? Fastest way to get back would be O(nlogn) - merge sort. O(n) if it's just one swap...

Comment: So you are given that B is a sorted array except for exactly one swap of random elements?

Comment: @cricket_007: Methinks Idos would disagree (as would I).

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without additional information about what you are actually trying to do. Atm I'd say the fastest way to get A is not to give up a reference to A in the first place - e.g. by cloning A before swaping the elements...

Comment: Worst case will be for sure O(n), as you might hit swapped elements at the very end of search. But it gets more interesting if you hit swapped element early - in theory, instead of doing plain iteration to find other swapped one, you could try to do some kind of fancy binary search on the rest of the array. Would get bit more complex due to possibility of hitting swapped one early in search, but with long enough array, it might be even cost effective to do neighbour check on each access. It will be O(n), but you may end with something like n/3 + 2*logn operations instead of n on average.

Comment: The worst case complexity must be at least O(n), in other words, one must read at least all but 2 element. If some algorithm claims it can complete the work without ever reading 3 elements, then an adversary can put the swapped pair in that 3 elements and the algorithm will not know what to swap to recover the array A.

Comment: Technically speaking, the cost in space is O(1), not O(N), as you need no extra array.

Comment: Your "naive way" is O(N Log(N)), not O(N) !

Answer (score 2):

Just search the swapped elements starting from the left and from the right and swap them when found.

```
// Let' assume the array is stored in a variable 'arr'

private void restoreArray() {
    swap(getLeftSwapIndex(), getRightSwapIndex());
}

private void swap(int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

private void getLeftSwapIndex() {
    for (int i=0 ; i<arr.length-1 ; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) return i;
    }
    return 0; // does not happen
}

private void getRightSwapIndex() {
    for (int i=arr.length-1 ; i>0 ; i--) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i-1]) return i;
    }
    return 0; // does not happen
}
```

Comment: Isn't `getLeftSwapIndex() == getRightSwapIndex()-1`?

Comment: In [1,2,6,4,5,3,7,8] you would get 2 and 5 as left and right index.